# Problem With Custom Control on Page Using a MasterPage

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a content page which has a related master page.
I register a prefix <%@ TagPrefix ..... and can load other custom controls at that namespace.
However, one particualar control at the same namespace, when added to the aspx page, breaks it.
The control in question inherits from asp:Panel, has a parameterless constructor, defines a few public accessors, and creates some standard child controls, and nothing much else.

Are there some fundamental restrictions to creating custom asp controls that I am breaking unknowingly?

Comment: Could you clarify how things are broken? Currently, your question does not provide information that would allow us to resolve your problem.

Comment: When I add the control to the content page ('[<customNS:customCntl ID="asd" ... />'), the page is then invalid, I get Unknown Error. If I comment it out, page loads as expected, obviously without my control though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the control back to the page.  Delete the designer file for the page: .aspx.designer.cs

Then right click on the page and select Convert to Web Application.  This should give you the actual error the page has when attempting to write the control definition to your designer file.

I suspect there is a compilation error in your custom control.

Comment: @Paul: glad this worked out for you.  I use this trick all the time to figure out what's failing in user controls.  I wish VS would just report the actual error you get with this method instead of the generic one it has.

Answer (score 0):

My control was attempting to access Page.Header which was null as the master page had not marked the  tag with runat="server".

I guess that is a fundamental restriction that I was looking for...